# How to filter null returning method in stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list, it has some method like getSummary(), and this method returns null in some cases. How can I filter to avoid getting the null result?

Here is my code:

```
List<Event> items = getEvents(sharedCalendarId, startDateTime, endDateTime, zoneId);

if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(items)) {
    openingHoursDto.setBranches(items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getSummary))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> {
                LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto lBOHDto = new LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto();
                lBOHDto.setName(e.getKey());
                lBOHDto.setDates(getHoursDtoMap(e.getValue(), startDateTime, endDateTime, selfServicePattern, specialHoursColorId, zoneId));
                return lBOHDto;
            })
            .sorted(comparing(LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto::getName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return openingHoursDto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a filter step:

```
openingHoursDto.setBranches(items.stream()
        .filter (e -> e.getSummary() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getSummary))
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `.stream() .filter(Objects::notNull)`

Comment: This approach results in a different behavior than the one required. This code line will filter all instances of the Event class that are null, allowing all non-null event instances to pass through the filter. Not null instances of the Event class whose event.getSummary() method returns null will pass the filter.

Answer (score 1):

A [filter predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)), like the following, needs to be added in the [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

`.filter(event -> event.getSummary() != null)`

The code after the addition is provided hereafter for reference:

```
List<Event> items = getEvents(sharedCalendarId, startDateTime, endDateTime, zoneId);

if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(items)) {
    openingHoursDto.setBranches(items.stream()
             //filter to keep only events with non-null event.getSummary()
            .filter(event -> event.getSummary() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getSummary))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> {
                LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto lBOHDto = new LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto();
                lBOHDto.setName(e.getKey());
                lBOHDto.setDates(getHoursDtoMap(e.getValue(), startDateTime, endDateTime, selfServicePattern, specialHoursColorId, zoneId));
                return lBOHDto;
            })
            .sorted(comparing(LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto::getName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return openingHoursDto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you don't need to validate if  `List<Event> items` is empty or not, stream will not be processed if there are no elements..

```
openingHoursDto.setBranches(items.stream()
                 //filter to not only null but also empty string 
                 // or use .filter(Objects::nonNull) for the whole object to be filtered
                .filter(event -> !event.getSummary().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getSummary))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                ..map(this::toLBOHDto)
                .sorted(comparing(LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto::getName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return openingHoursDto;




    private LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto toLBOHDto(Event e){
        LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto lBOHDto = new LibraryBranchOpeningHoursDto();
        lBOHDto.setName(e.getKey());
        lBOHDto.setDates(getHoursDtoMap(e.getValue(), startDateTime, endDateTime, selfServicePattern, specialHoursColorId, zoneId));
        return lBOHDto;
    }
```

it is better practice to have your mapping outside the stream operation like making it a method,
or you can have it as you have it

Comment: Using event.getSummary().isEmpty() will throw a NullPointerException when event.getSummary() returns null. Moreover since filtering is required, event.getSummary() is anticipated to return null. So a NullPointerException is anticipated here during runtime.

Comment: @SpyrosK yes you are right the validation of stream is on the event object not on the getSummery() which in that case can be filtered by != null. thanks for the comment